# Как лучше сделать смену разметок на одном экране?

Tags: java, android

На основном экране есть "шапка" с навигацией, которая будет одинаковой (head.xml).

Нужно чтобы в оставшуюся часть (под шапкой) загружались разные разметки (scr1.xml, scr2.xml, scr3.xml).

С помощью чего это лучше делать? 
Пробовал с помощью ViewFlipper, но хотелось бы узнать о других способах.

Comment: а с помощью viewpager не пробовал?

Comment: ViewPager в сочетании с TabLayout

Comment: Почитал про viewpager. ViewFlipper - мне кажется проще. Но вопрос в том, что лучше использовать.

Comment: лучше использовать viewpager, оно эффективно и не трудно реализовать

Comment: в viewpager можно использовать навигацию без всяких усилий

Comment: Flipper оказался проще в реализации, к тому же мне не нужен эффект листания экранов. Я просто создаю массив лайаутов и выбираю нужный. Но все таки надеюсь, что кто нибудь предложит еще варианты.